# Shuffle pivoted PySpark DataFrame rows throws a NullPointedException

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose the next PySpark DataFrame:

```
+-------+----+---+---+----+
|user_id|type| d1| d2|  d3|
+-------+----+---+---+----+
|     c1|   A|3.4|0.4| 3.5|
|     c1|   B|9.6|0.0| 0.0|
|     c1|   A|2.8|0.4| 0.3|
|     c1|   B|5.4|0.2|0.11|
|     c2|   A|0.0|9.7| 0.3|
|     c2|   B|9.6|8.6| 0.1|
|     c2|   A|7.3|9.1| 7.0|
|     c2|   B|0.7|6.4| 4.3|
+-------+----+---+---+----+
```

created with:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("c1", "A", 3.4, 0.4, 3.5), 
    ("c1", "B", 9.6, 0.0, 0.0),
    ("c1", "A", 2.8, 0.4, 0.3),
    ("c1", "B", 5.4, 0.2, 0.11),
    ("c2", "A", 0.0, 9.7, 0.3), 
    ("c2", "B", 9.6, 8.6, 0.1),
    ("c2", "A", 7.3, 9.1, 7.0),
    ("c2", "B", 0.7, 6.4, 4.3)
]).toDF(["user_id", "type", "d1", "d2", "d3"])
df.show()
```

Then, it's pivoted by `user_id` to obtain:

```
data_wide = df.groupBy('user_id')\
.pivot('type')\
.agg(*[f.sum(x).alias(x) for x in df.columns if x not in {"user_id", "type"}])

data_wide.show()

+-------+-----------------+------------------+----+------------------+----+------------------+
|user_id|             A_d1|              A_d2|A_d3|              B_d1|B_d2|              B_d3|
+-------+-----------------+------------------+----+------------------+----+------------------+
|     c1|6.199999999999999|               0.8| 3.8|              15.0| 0.2|              0.11|
|     c2|              7.3|18.799999999999997| 7.3|10.299999999999999|15.0|4.3999999999999995|
+-------+-----------------+------------------+----+------------------+----+------------------+
```

Now, I want to randomize its rows order:

```
data_wide = data_wide.orderBy(f.rand())
data_wide.show()
```

But this last step throws a `NullPointedException`:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o101.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 161 in stage 27.0 failed 20 times, most recent failure: Lost task 161.19 in stage 27.0 (TID 1300, 192.168.192.57, executor 1): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_3$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateResultProjection$1.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:232)
```

However, if the wide df is cached before the `orderBy(f.rand())` step, this last step works fine:

```
data_wide.cache()
data_wide = data_wide.orderBy(f.rand())
data_wide.show()

+-------+-----------------+------------------+----+------------------+----+------------------+
|user_id|             A_d1|              A_d2|A_d3|              B_d1|B_d2|              B_d3|
+-------+-----------------+------------------+----+------------------+----+------------------+
|     c2|              7.3|18.799999999999997| 7.3|10.299999999999999|15.0|4.3999999999999995|
|     c1|6.199999999999999|               0.8| 3.8|              15.0| 0.2|              0.11|
+-------+-----------------+------------------+----+------------------+----+------------------+
```

What is the problem here? It seems that, in the `orderBy` step, the pivot has not been made effective and it does not plan the execution correctly, but I do not know what the actual problem is. Any ideas?

Spark version is 2.1.0 and python version is 3.5.2

Thank you in advance

Comment: This works for me on 2.3.1 without caching... What versions of python and pyspark are you using?

Comment: @coldspeed I'm sorry, spark version is 2.1.0 and python 3.5.2. It seems a version problem. I've edited the question, thank you.

Comment: Will a simple update fix it for you?

Comment: works for me in spark 2.3.0

Comment: Yes! A simple update fix it, thank you